# Are oranges actually green?

Tags: biology

On an episode of Qi there was a 'fact' that claimed oranges aren't actually orange they are green and they lose their green colour in transport and become orange.

Now I was indeed skeptical about this, surely they are just green when they are unripe, like a lot of fruits and I'm pretty sure I have seen pictures of orange trees with orange oranges on them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the claim. This sounds like a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: The claim is here and it's quite different: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/the-filter/qi/8345477/QI-Quite-interesting-facts-about-orange.html

Comment: Here's an example of the claim [on the QI forums](http://old.qi.com/talk/viewtopic.php?t=24578&start=0&sid=8db906776493daf92ce3c02fe9916f0e).  And a similar claim (that provides an answer) [on io9](http://io9.com/everything-you-know-is-wrong-oranges-aren-t-orange-1097312640).

Comment: In practice, they don't claim this at all, they claim that it depends on the temperature (so not dissimilar from what the OP thinks are the facts).

Comment: Right, in any case this was not claimed on QI as far as I can tell, so the question needs fixing.

Comment: @Sklivvz look in general ignorance section http://www.comedy.co.uk/guide/tv/qi/episodes/8/3/

Comment: Did you read the article I linked? It is by the QI authors and disagrees that they said what is claimed above. Now, I don't doubt that the claim might be reasonable, but it's not by QI. Furthermore, since googling returns simply the opposite, I'd like to see a real claim. All that I can find claim they are colored with ethylene. Is this what the OP is doubtful about?

Comment: I've never said anything like that. The claim was about changing colors in transport, now it's about supermarket coloring them. In the meanwhile the edit made the only answer off topic.

Comment: I've rolled back to the original claim. The OP can ask a different question, instead of changing this once it's already answered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12467/discussion-between-sklivvz-and-articuno)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=orange%20tree&tbs=imgo:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's wrong.

Oranges are/can be orange in their trees, as they get mature.

Sources: http://www.ba.ars.usda.gov/hb66/100orange.pdf

> Peel color at maturity ranges from light to deep orange but may remain green under warm conditions

One research analysis how the water ammount can change the fruit color: http://ucce.ucdavis.edu/files/datastore/234-2628.pdf

> "Our research suggests that late-season
>   water stress may produce a fruit with less
>   green and more orange color earlier in the
>   season when even a few days difference in
>   harvest timing can mean a large price differential
>   in fruit value."

Comment: So it seems that it is possible for them to be green, depending on temperature and maturity.

Comment: but certainely not enough to start calling them greens

Comment: @jammycoder for what I could understand, they can be green, not that they are always, all, green...